# Convert Time to just Number in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I have a field in my form that is saved in a time format

```
t.time :time_from
```

When saving a time it is saved like this in the DB

```
2000-01-01 18:00:00 UTC
```

However I would like to display the output as 18:00 in my view. How would I go about converting this using a helper for example?

Do I need to save it in a better format when going in to the DB or will a helper suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
time.strftime("%H:%M")
```

Answer (score 3):

I work on a project that must always be internationalized and the use of [i18n.l](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) helper has proven to be ideal.

I would recommend it for you case as well, apart from internationalization it is a very efficient way to keep track of used formats throughout the project.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails you can just use the `to_s` method that is aliased as [`to_formatted_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) passing the symbol `:time` as an argument:

```
Time.now.to_s(:time)
# => "18:11"
```